# Ignoring function in JSON with JavaScript using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Highcharts to create some charts, more specifically I am using https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server in order to export the charts. A JSON file is used for the source of what the chart will contain(see JSON below).

I then read data from a file and want to replace the *data* property in the JSON file with what I read from the file, the problem I have is that the JSON contains a *function()* so when I use JSON.parse() it fails because a JSON cannot contain a function().

```
{
    "chart":{
        "type":"bar",
        "labels":{
            "style":{
                "fontFamily":"Arial",
                "fontSize":"14px"}
        },
        "events": {
                    "load": function() {
                        var plotBands = this.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands;
                        for (var i in plotBands) {
                            var d = plotBands[i].svgElem.d;
                            var dArray = d.split(" ");
                            var rect = {x:25, y:dArray[5], width: 540, height: 100};
                            this.renderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height)
                                .attr({
                                    fill: 'green'
                                })
                                .add();
                        }
                    }
         }
    },
    "xAxis":{
        "categories":[
        {"name":"Group A","categories":["Text A.1","Text A.2","Text A.3"]},
        {"name":"Group B","categories":["Text B.1","Text B.2","Text B.3"]},
        {"name":"Group C","categories":["Text C.1","Text C.2","Text C.3"]},
        {"name":"Group D","categories":["Text D.1","Text D.2","Text D.3"]},
        {"name":"Group E","categories":["Text E.1","Text E.2","Text E.3"]},
        {"name":"Group F","categories":["Text F.1","Text F.2","Text F.3"]},
        {"name":"Group G","categories":["Text G.1","Text G.2","Text G.3"]}],
        "labels":{
            "rotation":0,
            "style":{
                "fontFamily":"Arial",
                "fontSize":"14px",
                "overflow":"justify",
                "textOverflow":"none"
            }
        }
    },
    "yAxis":{
        "min":0,
        "max":100,
        "title":{"text":"y-values"},
        "style":{
            "fontSize":"14px",
            "overflow":"justify"
        }
    },
    "series":[{
        "type":"bar",
        "name":"Score",
        "data":[20,20,43,80,20,10,65,88,35,62,48,85,63,20,13,54,34,100,23,55,76],
        "color":"red"
    }]
}
```

This is the code line that fails

```
var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('jsonFile.json', 'utf-8'));
```

Is there a way around this issue? Can I ignore the function in some way because I am not interesting in reading its content anyhow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the `jsonFile.json` contain a function? You should fix the problem at its origin, and that would be to ensure that `jsonFile.json` contains only valid data.

Comment: You can use `eval`, `var m = eval("(" + fs.readFileSync('jsonFile.json', 'utf-8') + ")");`

Comment: @ponury-kostek, your code will throw.

Comment: @Qwertiy right, fixed

Comment: You could create your own function that accepts a row of chart data and returns valid JSON.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for answering, unfortunately I wasn't sure how to solve it in any other way. I tried to call the events load function as a callback but failed to do so, probably because of my little experience in JavaScript. The eval function proposed by others here seems to solve my problem, would it be bad practice to use it?

Comment: @Fjodor then you shouldn't call that file `.json` but name it `.js` and write `module.exports = {  "chart":{  ... `. And import it using `var m = require('file.js')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is **trusted** you may use `eval`:

```
var m = (0, eval)("(" + fs.readFileSync('jsonFile.json', 'utf-8') + ")");
```

Anyway, I **don't** recommend you to do so.

---

You should either remove function and make valid json or change file to `js`, add `module.exports =` there and then use normal `require` on it:

```
var m = require('jsonFile.js');
```